# Can't delete printf I wrote for testing in the beginnig

Tags: c

I have a function to read data from text file to a linked list. In the beginnig I put a printf statement to test if the dates read by fscanf was assigned to variables in the list. Now I completed my program. Everything works fine if printf statement is there. But when I delete it the programs stops working after compiling. And for the love of me I can't seem to figure out why. I can also post the whole code if it is needed. I didn't because it was a little bit long.

Text file is like this.

```
1;ladygaga;3289;50;44000000;10/01/2020 09:12
2;ricky_martin;1771;1427;14700000;25/05/2020 00:15
```

Here is the struct:

```c
struct node
{
    int id;
    char name[25];
    int posts;
    int following;
    int followers;
    char date[20];
    char time [20];
    struct node* next;
};
```

This is the function

```
struct node* initialiseMyAccount(char filename[20])
{
    int tmp_id, tmp_posts, tmp_following, tmp_followers;
    char tmp_name[25], tmp_date[20], tmp_time[20];
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    struct node *tmp, *head, *last, *first;
    head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    head->next = NULL;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%s %s\n", &tmp_id, tmp_name, &tmp_posts, &tmp_following, &tmp_followers, tmp_date, tmp_time) != EOF)
    {
        tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tmp->id=tmp_id;
        strcpy(tmp->name, tmp_name);
        tmp->posts=tmp_posts;
        tmp->following=tmp_following;
        tmp->followers=tmp_followers;
        strcpy(tmp->date, tmp_date);
        strcpy(tmp->time, tmp_time);
        printf("%d %s %d %d %d %s %s\n", tmp->id, tmp->name, tmp->posts, tmp->following, tmp->followers, tmp->date, tmp->time); 
// I wrote the above printf to check if assigning values to the list worked. But the program doesn't work when I delete it.
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(head->next==NULL)
        {
            head->next = tmp;
            first = last = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = tmp;
            last = tmp;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}
```

And this is how i call it in main

```
int main()
{
    struct node *followers, *following;
    char filename[20]="followers.txt";
    followers=initialiseMyAccount(filename);
    strcpy(filename, "following.txt");
    following=initialiseMyAccount(filename);
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(...) != EOF)` - for good code, don't compare with EOF, compare with count of elements scanned. For example `scanf` may have scanned 2 elements, but less then all. | please post `struct node` definition. Please post compilable [MCVE], at beast including all the `#include` and short `int main()` that would compile and reproduce the problem. What is the input? Does the fields have more then __24__ or __19__ characters? What does `scanf` return? Does it scan successfully all fields?

Comment: @dokan Can you post something from your main, like when you call the functions and sendig the parameters

Comment: @dokan Pls edit your code with that information! You has a error I dont know if is from that but on malloc on tmp you forget the `*` on `sizeof` so need to be `tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));`

Comment: @GonçaloBastos oh sorry. i'm on it.

Comment: The trailing newline in `fscanf(fp, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%s %s\n", …` is dangerous.  If the input comes from a terminal, it is a lethal UX.  The trouble is, the `fscanf()` call reads any white space, up to but not including the next non-white space character, newlines and all.  If the input comes from a file, it usually isn't so harmful, but it is usually unnecessary.  The `%d` at the start will skip white space (including newlines), so the trailing white space really isn't necessary.

Comment: @GonçaloBastos I have edited it with the struct itself and how i call the function. About malloc. I wrote it like that in the beginnig but it was only getting tmp->id not the other. I post a question here and i was told to remove * and it worked.

Comment: @dokan It's most probably a memory error try to run it with valgrind to have more details

Comment: @dokan Provide us the followers.txt and following.txt

Comment: @GonçaloBastos text is like this. variables of the struct seperated by semicolon.
1;ladygaga;3289;50;44000000;10/01/2020 09:12
2;ricky_martin;1771;1427;14700000;25/05/2020 00:15

Comment: @dokan: please insert the sample data into the question where you can format it so it is understandable.

Comment: @dokan I found where your problem is, but I dont know why is giving error

Comment: `head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));` is almost certainly wrong.  Use the idiom `head = malloc(sizeof *head);` and the size will be correct.  Unless a pointer is larger than the struct, your initialization is not allocating enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
```

Is not allocating enough space.  It allocates space for a pointer, which is not big enough to hold a `struct node`.  Use a different idiom:

```
head = malloc(sizeof *head);
```

Comment: But everything works fine using the first one. Searching throught the list, adding node, deleting node, printing the list. So why is it just printf making a problem?

Comment: Memory issues like this give rise to undefined behavior.  The fact that omitting the call to `printf` changes the behavior of your program show that it does not "work fine" using the first case, merely that the undefined behavior exhibited matches your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that your problem is on this line! I dont know why but when I uncomment gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct node{
    int id;
    char name[25];
    int posts;
    int following;
    int followers;
    char date[20];
    char time [20];
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* initialiseMyAccount(char filename[20])
{
    int tmp_id, tmp_posts, tmp_following, tmp_followers;
    char tmp_name[25], tmp_date[20], tmp_time[20];
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    struct node *tmp, *head, *last, *first;
    head=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    head->next = NULL;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%s %s\n", &tmp_id, tmp_name, &tmp_posts, &tmp_following, &tmp_followers, tmp_date, tmp_time) != EOF)
    {
        tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tmp->id=tmp_id;
        strcpy(tmp->name, tmp_name);
        tmp->posts=tmp_posts;
        tmp->following=tmp_following;
        tmp->followers=tmp_followers;
        strcpy(tmp->date, tmp_date);
        strcpy(tmp->time, tmp_time); 
        printf("%d %s %d %d %d %s %s\n", tmp->id, tmp->name, tmp->posts, tmp->following, tmp->followers, tmp->date, tmp->time); 
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(head->next==NULL)
        {
            head->next = tmp;
            first = last = tmp;
        }
        else{
            //last->next = tmp; ------> THIS LINE
            last = head;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}

int main()
{
 
    struct node *followers;
    char filename[20]="followers.txt";
    followers=initialiseMyAccount(filename);
}
```

I am using the file like this:

```
1;ladygaga;3289;50;44000000;10/01/2020 09:12 
2;ricky_martin;1771;1427;14700000;25/05/2020 00:15
```

**With the line commented:**

[image]

Comment: If I delete last->next = tmp; it doesn't store the next ones. only the first.

Comment: You already has the solution! I didnt figured out why!